# Why http request is automatically redirected to https on a freshly installed httpd server on redhat?

Tags: apache, redirect

I have a red hat linux server version 6.2 and just installed httpd server on it. After deploying a DJango application on it, i found that http request to the server is automatically redirected to https like below. I doubled check my httpd.conf and 100% sure that I don't configure any port like 443 and there's no mod_ssl installed ( had installed but removed afterwards).

That sounds weird and I took many hours on it but no luck.

```
>wget http://myserver
Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx ....connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 MOVED PERMANTENTLY
Location: https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/ [following]
connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:443...failed: Connection refueds.
```

Comment: Any `.htaccess` file in your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: No, I don't find this file under DocumentRoot, nor does it exist in my machine anywhere actually.

Comment: Could you add the Apache configuration entries for `myserver`? Like `VirtualHost` it that is what you are using. The redirect is not made by `mod_ssl` but probably by a `RewriteRule` or `Redirect` in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an [SSL auto-redirect](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) in your configuration?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```